# Ganglia Network monitoring Calculate values out of rrd files

Tags: rrdtool, rrd, ganglia

Im searching for some documentary but i couldnt really find anything and im really confused about the network monitoring in Ganglia. So i want to know how much network traffic my hosts have.

If i use the webinterface im seeing this graph : [image]

That is already kind of confusing for me since it says Bytes/sec on the left but then theres M for Megabyte i guess and the in is in K so KiloBytes i guess? Well so far so good this graph doesnt give me to much details so im checking the bytes_out.rrd in my Ganglia directory to see how much MB were send out in Detail. So i got these Data :

```
<!-- 2014-08-13 11:44:00 CEST / 1407923040 --> <row><v>7.7329800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:44:15 CEST / 1407923055 --> <row><v>8.2289393333e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:44:30 CEST / 1407923070 --> <row><v>8.7957500000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:44:45 CEST / 1407923085 --> <row><v>1.4574438000e+04</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:45:00 CEST / 1407923100 --> <row><v>2.3242470000e+04</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:45:15 CEST / 1407923115 --> <row><v>2.3242470000e+04</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:45:30 CEST / 1407923130 --> <row><v>2.3145348820e+06</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:45:45 CEST / 1407923145 --> <row><v>5.7514735000e+06</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:46:00 CEST / 1407923160 --> <row><v>5.7514735000e+06</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:46:15 CEST / 1407923175 --> <row><v>7.4439770000e+06</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:46:30 CEST / 1407923190 --> <row><v>1.0828984000e+07</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:46:45 CEST / 1407923205 --> <row><v>8.8717527333e+06</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:47:00 CEST / 1407923220 --> <row><v>3.4893667500e+06</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:47:15 CEST / 1407923235 --> <row><v>3.4893667500e+06</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:47:30 CEST / 1407923250 --> <row><v>8.6100076167e+06</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:47:45 CEST / 1407923265 --> <row><v>2.2691770000e+07</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:48:00 CEST / 1407923280 --> <row><v>2.2691770000e+07</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:48:15 CEST / 1407923295 --> <row><v>2.2899696800e+07</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:48:30 CEST / 1407923310 --> <row><v>2.3731404000e+07</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:48:45 CEST / 1407923325 --> <row><v>2.6172286400e+07</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:49:00 CEST / 1407923340 --> <row><v>3.5935816000e+07</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:49:15 CEST / 1407923355 --> <row><v>3.5935816000e+07</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:49:30 CEST / 1407923370 --> <row><v>2.8771658410e+07</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:49:45 CEST / 1407923385 --> <row><v>1.1502805000e+05</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:50:00 CEST / 1407923400 --> <row><v>1.1502805000e+05</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:50:15 CEST / 1407923415 --> <row><v>1.1158186333e+05</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:50:30 CEST / 1407923430 --> <row><v>1.0468949000e+05</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:50:45 CEST / 1407923445 --> <row><v>9.9945940667e+04</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:51:00 CEST / 1407923460 --> <row><v>8.6901180000e+04</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:51:15 CEST / 1407923475 --> <row><v>8.6901180000e+04</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:51:30 CEST / 1407923490 --> <row><v>7.7706996000e+04</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:51:45 CEST / 1407923505 --> <row><v>5.2422990000e+04</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:52:00 CEST / 1407923520 --> <row><v>5.2422990000e+04</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:52:15 CEST / 1407923535 --> <row><v>5.5379930000e+04</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:52:30 CEST / 1407923550 --> <row><v>6.1293810000e+04</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:52:45 CEST / 1407923565 --> <row><v>6.1999703333e+04</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:53:00 CEST / 1407923580 --> <row><v>6.3940910000e+04</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:53:15 CEST / 1407923595 --> <row><v>6.3940910000e+04</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:53:30 CEST / 1407923610 --> <row><v>4.8976235333e+04</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:53:45 CEST / 1407923625 --> <row><v>7.8233800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:54:00 CEST / 1407923640 --> <row><v>7.8233800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:54:15 CEST / 1407923655 --> <row><v>7.8233800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:54:30 CEST / 1407923670 --> <row><v>7.8233800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:54:45 CEST / 1407923685 --> <row><v>7.8233800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:55:00 CEST / 1407923700 --> <row><v>7.8233800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:55:15 CEST / 1407923715 --> <row><v>7.8233800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:55:30 CEST / 1407923730 --> <row><v>7.8233800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:55:45 CEST / 1407923745 --> <row><v>7.8233800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:56:00 CEST / 1407923760 --> <row><v>7.8233800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:56:15 CEST / 1407923775 --> <row><v>7.8233800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:56:30 CEST / 1407923790 --> <row><v>7.8233800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:56:45 CEST / 1407923805 --> <row><v>7.8233800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:57:00 CEST / 1407923820 --> <row><v>7.8233800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:57:15 CEST / 1407923835 --> <row><v>7.8233800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:57:30 CEST / 1407923850 --> <row><v>7.8233800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:57:45 CEST / 1407923865 --> <row><v>7.8233800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:58:00 CEST / 1407923880 --> <row><v>7.8233800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:58:15 CEST / 1407923895 --> <row><v>7.8233800000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:58:30 CEST / 1407923910 --> <row><v>7.8273046667e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:58:45 CEST / 1407923925 --> <row><v>7.8822500000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:59:00 CEST / 1407923940 --> <row><v>7.8822500000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:59:15 CEST / 1407923955 --> <row><v>7.8822500000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:59:30 CEST / 1407923970 --> <row><v>7.8822500000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 11:59:45 CEST / 1407923985 --> <row><v>7.8822500000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 12:00:00 CEST / 1407924000 --> <row><v>7.8822500000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 12:00:15 CEST / 1407924015 --> <row><v>7.8822500000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 12:00:30 CEST / 1407924030 --> <row><v>7.8822500000e+03</v></row>
            <!-- 2014-08-13 12:00:45 CEST / 1407924045 --> <row><v>7.8822500000e+03</v></row>
```

So there should be some traffic around 6-8MB right before 12:00. But i cant see how that value shows that. I calculated the value at 11:47:45 for example.

If i take the E+07 as ^7 i get something around 309,XX so what should that be? if i take it as decimals i get something around 22691770 if i think its Bytes or Kilobytes and divid it by 1024 i will end up at 21,XX which isnt my 6-8MB aswell. So how do i calculate these values?

I got that these are the avg values for a 15 second period. But it should be Bytes/Sec if i see the graphs writing. But i dont really see how that numbers can be around 6-8mb/s.

Anyone knows how to calculate or where to find some detailed documentation? I used rrdtool dump btw to get these values ...

Answer (score 0):

The 'E+07' notation to which you are referring, is interpreted as 'times 10 to the 7th power.'
So, in your example,

```
2.2691770000e+07
```

would equal 22,692,770.  That number, also, is not evident in the graph; however, I believe the graph does some amount of aggregation, perhaps one new plot point per minute...?  So I imagine you're going to see discrepancies.
When I averaged the 4 values for the minute of 11:47, I got around 9.6M.